# Approach to Saving a game in Unity3D

Tags: save, unity-game-engine

I have searched a lot on how to save a game in Unity 3D. Everyone has advised to use XML serialization or Player Prefs. What i am unable to figure out is what exactly to save. My game is a tower Defence game so when I quit i need to save

- Towers (multiple Prefabs , location and each on a particular
  upgrade,animation currently playing etc)
- Enemies (multiple enemy prefabs on the battle field, their position , animation , enemy path
  , health etc)
- Enemy Wave
- Path Calculations
- Difficulty
- Level
- Score
- Lives Left
- Total money

what should be my approach trying to save all this information. What is the level of granularity I will have to go to ? . Can I save every gameObject and everything related to that game object will be automatically saved. or do i save every class ? ... or do i need to save every variable used in the game.

Comment: If you only allow saving between waves, you won't have to take that much data (animations, enemy data, etc) into account.

Comment: Skip saving animation info, that's overkill.  Same with path.  Your engine should be smart enough to recalculate those based on current game state.  What to save is harder to answer, it really depends on your game.  Typically you'll save values that can't be generated by the current game state.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your code design. But avoid saving all data (like serialisation). All that have initial default values or non-important for player (such animation position) should save only changed properties. After game is loaded you should create objects from scratch, init them and set values from saved file.

For simple games can suggest to use Player Prefs to just save such info as current level, score.

For saving thousands of random objects consider saving control points and restore level loading them and regenerate random points around them.

Also good approach is to save data into web cloud.